# Extract out substrings into separate columns SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, substring

I am trying to extract certain parts of the a string into separate column but can't figure out how to do it. My database looks like this: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/10084a9/2

```
`CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `profile` (
  `user` varchar(200) NOT NULL
) DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

INSERT INTO `profile` (`user`) VALUES
  ("history/myprofile/Alice/1992/30.pdf"),
  ("location/area/active/Nyme/2000/1/12/1002");
```

[image]
and I want to create a columns in the database representing the extracted out values which will always be last 3 or 5 in the string above, for example this is my desired output from the table above.

[image]

What I have tried:

```
select * SPLIT_PART(user,'/', 3) as name
FROM profile ;
```

This works in some cases if the string is in the right position in this case 3 but if not then it extracts the wrong string.
EDIT
The string doesn't have any common substring but If it makes it any easier I really only need the numbers from the end and those are the only numbers in the user column e.g., 1992/30 and 2000/1/12/1002 which are always at the end. These numbers will only be either in last 2 or 4 position before the dot

Comment: Does 'User' column value has any specific pattern?

Comment: Not really, sorry. If it makes it any easier I really only need the numbers from the end and those are the only numbers in the user column e.g., 1992/30 and 2000/1/12/1002 which are always at the end. These numbers will only be either last 2 or 4 before the dot.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [**SUBSTRING_INDEX**](https://www.w3resource.com/mysql/string-functions/mysql-substring_index-function.php) to achieve this and try below sample query but you need to have standard values to address it.

```
SELECT user, SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(user, '/', 1), '/', -1) as name,
     SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(user, '/', 2), '/', -1) as year,
     SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(user, '/', 3), '/', -1) as batch,
     SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(user, '/', 4), '/', -1) as status,
     SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(user, '/', 5), '/', -1) as value
FROM profile;
```

**[SQL FIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/b89f42/5)**

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer but this also extracts information that is not required. As I only need the numbers is it possible to filter the string and then extract them out?

Comment: Also, just realised anything I need to extract will have myprofile or active before